can not set unciodepwd in java
ad on windows server 2016
we want to update password using java
upd pwd code  :
try {

            String dn = "CN=adminad,OU=NewUser";

            String pwd1 = "1QAZ,2wsx";

            ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];

            Attribute attr0 = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", mkPwd(pwd1));

            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attr0);

            ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);

            Thread.sleep(500);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

for making pwd ,we used code for function mkPwd:
     String pwd1 = "\"" + password + "\"";

            return pwd1.getBytes("UTF-16LE");`

and also used code for function mkPwd:
 String quotedPassword = "\"" + pwd + "\"";

            char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();

            byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++)

            {

            pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);

            pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);

            }

            return pwdArray;

all return error :

[LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A126A, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

so how to update ad password in java ,thank you .
so how to update ad password in java

You must meet the following requirements:

Security: Active Directory requires secure communication (LDAP over SSL/TLS) to modify sensitive attributes like passwords.
Encoding: Passwords are stored in a specific format (UnicodePwd) that requires encoding before being sent.
Permissions: The Java application needs sufficient permissions to modify user objects in Active Directory.


thanks for reply ,could you please tell me if the code we encoding password right ?

@dtbtb We have some code that we have used at: https://github.com/jwilleke/LDAP-Examples

thank you ,u are right ,key is conn must be ssl

and conn user must hav permisson
